# Report matching time stamps from automatically triggered lambda functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am using Amazon Cloud Watch to trigger 4 different lambda functions every twelve hours.  The lambda functions pull some data from an api and save it to my database.  I want to make sure that the timestamp matches for the data on all my lambda functions.  Initially I used the PostgreSQL default `timestamp` however this records time to the millisecond which introduces small discrepancies in time.

It seems like the Cloud Watch rule which invokes my lambda functions might be able to pass along an identical time stamp but I haven't been able to figure out how to do this, or even verify if it is possible.

I really don't need the time stamp to go to the minute.  Mostly I am concerned with the date and whether it was the AM or PM batch so knowing time to the nearest hour is good enough.

If any AWS experts could lend me some advice it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The scheduled CloudWatch (CW) Event rule passes the following `event` object to the lambda function, e.g.:

```
{
    "version": "0",
    "id": "a75ba59d-81d6-8363-8e68-593f7de30b09",
    "detail-type": "Scheduled Event",
    "source": "aws.events",
    "account": "32323232",
    "time": "2021-02-21T06:29:27Z",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "resources": [
        "arn:aws:events:us-east-1:32323232:rule/test"
    ],
    "detail": {}
}
```

As you can see, `time` is measured to the second. Also CW **does not guarantee exact execution** of it events. They [can be off](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html) by 1 minute:

> Your scheduled rule is triggered within that minute, but not on the precise 0th second

So your four functions will have slightly different `time`. Thus, you have to manage that in your code - round it to nearest hour for example.

The alternative is to use your lambda environment build in tools for getting **timestamp**, instead of using `time` from `event`. This can be easier as you can just get timestamp with precision of 1 hour directly, rather then parse the `time` from `event` and the post-process it to get desired precision.